# Show that mapping is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$. Exhibit a subset of the metric space $C(I)$ (uniform metric), which is unbounded. Show that mapping $f\to \int_{0}^{1}f$ of $C(I)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $C(I)$

attempt:

Trying to show that $sup|f(x)-g(x)|\le \delta\Longrightarrow |\int_{0}^{1}f-\int_{0}^{1}g|\le \epsilon$

However, I'm stuck on trying to find a function in C(I), which is unbounded?

Comment: Is your condition that any function $f\in C(I)$ is unbounded? Or that the space itself $C(I)$ is unbounded?

Comment: You have to think in terms of subsets of the given metric space $C(I)$. A single function is a single point in this metric space. How can a set composed of a single point be unbounded?

Answer (score 0):

$|\int\limits_{0}^{1}{f}-\int\limits_{0}^{1}{g}|\leq \int\limits_{0}^{1}{|f-g|dx}\leq \|f-g\|_\infty \cdot 1\leq \epsilon$ for each $\delta<\epsilon$.

Note: you do not need this unbounded subset of $C(I)$ in the beginning.

In general, if $F: X\to \mathbb R$ is a bounded linear functional (like in your case) with a norm $\|F\|_{X^*}$ then $|F(f)-F(g)|=|F(f-g)|\leq \|F\|_{X^*}\|f-g\|_X\leq \epsilon$ for each $\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}{\|F\|_{X^*}}$